# Build failure in JENKINS

Tags: python, python-3.x, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm facing issue in scheduling a job in JENKINS.The below command is working fine in TERMINAL(Mac) with and without SUDO(Have to enter password).

Without Sudo i'm getting "Operation not Permitted" error.

Below the build statement and error which i got in JENKINS, Can anyone please help me to resolve it?

```
export PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH:-"/Users/it/Documents/google_crawler"}
cd /Users/it/Documents/google_crawler
sudo python3 PLA_Google_continious_execution.py
```

Also instead of this "sudo python3 PLA_Google_continious_execution.py" tried "sudo python3 PLA_Google_continious_execution.py -S "password" "but same result.

**Error:**

```
09:45:47 Started by timer
09:45:47 Running as SYSTEM
09:45:47 Building in workspace /Users/it/.jenkins/workspace/google_crawler
09:45:47 [google_crawler] $ /bin/sh -xe /var/folders/t2/sk1vw_mn7mz7ncjw75lzh7r40000gn/T/jenkins4461665640429805517.sh
09:45:48 + export PYTHONPATH=/Users/it/Documents/google_crawler
09:45:48 + PYTHONPATH=/Users/it/Documents/google_crawler
09:45:48 + cd /Users/it/Documents/google_crawler
09:45:48 + sudo python3 PLA_Google_continious_execution.py
09:45:48 sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper
09:45:48 Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
09:45:48 Finished: FAILURE
```

Can anyone please guid eon this.

Answer (score 0):

> sudo: a terminal is required to read the password

Using this :

```
echo YOURPASSWORD | sudo -S python3 PLA_Google_continious_execution.py
```

Comment: Thanks for the update, But it doesn't work for me.After giving what you said, i'm getting the "operation Not Permitted"and "File can't be opened"error.Any suggestions on this?